# Getting no such group error in python script

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python, I am trying to run below script. I am getting IO error no such group found. I have specifically mentioned not to enter if None object is there.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

ERROR:

```
T663xt
count value inside if loop  T663xt
 After appending  ['T663xt']
AB12343
count value inside if loop  AB12343
 After appending  ['T663xt', 'AB12343']
None
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./KPHCcommandGenerator.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "./KPHCcommandGenerator.py", line 51, in main
    F1.ParsingFile ( InputFile )
  File "./KPHCcommandGenerator.py", line 38, in ParsingFile
    print arrayTemp.group( count )
IndexError: no such group
```

SOURCE CODE:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os.path
import fileinput
import re


#print "Hello World!!"
class checkingInputFile():
    array   =[] 
    def __init__( self ):
        print "Initializing file class"

    def checkFile ( self, file ):
        self.file = file
        #print ("I am in checkFile "+ file )
        try :
            if os.path.isfile ( self.file ) :
                print ( "File"+ self.file +" exists \n")
            else:
                print "file does not exists"
        except :
            print ( "File " + self.file + "does not exists" )

    def ParsingFile ( self, file ):
        self.file   =   file

        print ( "I am in switch command function" + self.file ) 
        for line in fileinput.input ( self.file ):
            #print ( line )     
            arrayTemp = re.search( r'^ARRAY_SERIAL #,(\w+),(\w+)?,(\w+)?(\w+)?,(\w+)?,.*', line, re.M|re.I )
            if arrayTemp :
                #print ("array lenght " + str(len(arrayTemp.group())) )
                count = 1
                while arrayTemp.group() is not None:
                    print arrayTemp.group( count )
                    #print "count value is ", count
                    if arrayTemp.group( count ) is not None :
                        print "count value inside if loop ",arrayTemp.group( count )
                        checkingInputFile.array.append( arrayTemp.group( count ) )
                        print  " After appending ",checkingInputFile.array
                    count = count + 1
        fileinput.close

def main ():
    InputFile = "/home/pradeep/Documents/Scripts/input.csv"
    F1 = checkingInputFile ()
    F1.checkFile( InputFile )
    F1.ParsingFile ( InputFile )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As we can see I am trying to iterate over tuple which I got form regular expression. I may have None values. I just want to add values that are not None to my global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove or comment out this print statement if possible since it throws the error before the real working code throws the error:

```
print arrayTemp.group( count )
```

Use a `try/except` block to catch the exception and handle it nicely when the group range is exceeded:

```
if arrayTemp.group( count ) is not None :
    try:
        print "count value inside if loop ",arrayTemp.group( count )
        checkingInputFile.array.append( arrayTemp.group( count ) )
        print  " After appending ",checkingInputFile.array
    except IndexError:
        break  # break this while loop
        arrayTemp = None  # breaks out of the outer for loop
```